# How can I make a SECOND checkbox with the same 'var' and 'getElementById'?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form called 'device'. This form has a checkbox. This checkbox has an ID. When this checkbox is checked, some text will appear (the Device Key).
I have made a button where a user can make a SECOND device (the form is called device).
When the user filled in all the things in the form, the user can submit the form. A second form will appear at the page.

This form is put in a while loop, so the second form has the same values.

What I want is a second checkbox who can use the same 'var' and 'getElementById'. Now I know that I must make a class instead of an ID, but then the first one doesn't work anymore..

```html
 <h2>Device</h2>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <div class="overviewcss">Hostnaam&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><?php echo $row['hostnaam'];  ?></b></div>
        <hr>
        <br>
            <div class="overviewcss">Url&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><?php echo $row['url']; ?></b></div>
        <hr>
        <br>
                <div class="overviewcss">Mac device&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><?php echo $row['devicemac']; ?></b></div>
        <hr>
        <br>

        <script>
            function showKey() {
                // Get the checkbox
                var checkBox = document.getElementById("showKey");
                // Get the output text
                var text = document.getElementById("outputText");

                // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
                if (checkBox.checked == true){
                    text.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    text.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div class="overviewcss">Device key&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="showKey" onclick="showKey()"></div>

        <p id="outputText" style="display:none"><b><?php echo $row['devicekey'] ?></b></p>
        <hr>
        <br>
<a href="update_form_device.php?devid=<?php echo $devid;?>" class="updatebtn">Wijzig</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="second_device.php" class="addseconddevice">Nog een device toevoegen</a>
    </div>
```

Can anyone help me? If you need more information, I will give it to you!

Thanks!

Comment: Just stop using an `id` in the first place and use a class instead. Then, instead of `getElementById()`, use `querySelector("classNameHere")`

Comment: `querySelector`delivers only the first element with this class. If you have perhaps more than one than use `querySelectorAll`. This delivers you an array even when there is only 1 with this class.

Comment: @ScottMarcus
I changed the "showWifiKey" id aswell to a class, but it doesn't work:

 <div class="overviewcss">Wi-Fi key&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="showWifiKey" onclick="showWifiKey()"></></div>

Comment: That doesn't work aswell unfortunately @Sascha

Comment: @Sascha If a replacement for `getElementById()` is desired, it's `querySelector()`, not `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Did you then replace `.getElementById("showKey")`, with `.querySelector(".showKey")` (**note the dot in front of the class name to denote that it is a class**)?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah, but it only shows the Device Key at the first checkbox, not at the second one